# How to compile Visual Basic into .exe manually?

Tags: vb.net

How can I compile a visual basic file (.vb) to .exe but manually? Like compiling a C# file to .exe with csc.exe?

Thanks.

Comment: use this https://superuser.com/questions/604953/how-can-i-compile-a-net-project-without-having-visual-studio-installed

Comment: The keyword to search is *commandline compiler*  Google reports 14,000 hits on this site.